# UIGridView from Array

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, gridview

I am using  [`UIGridView` Repo](https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView) to create a grid view of images from a feed. But when I am using the following code I get the same image filling all the grid.

```
-(UIGridViewCell *) gridView:(UIGridView *)grid cellForRowAt:(int)rowIndex AndColumnAt:(int)columnIndex
{
Cell *cell = (Cell *)[grid dequeueReusableCell];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[Cell alloc] init];
}


NSString *imageLink = [item objectForKey:@"link"];

NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageLink];
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

cell.thumbnail.image = image;
return cell;
}
```

How can I fill the grid with all the images from the array?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the array you speak of?

Comment: what's `item`? I assume it's an `NSDictionary`, but where does it get set to the correct one from your array?

Comment: Sorry I meant NSDictionary

Comment: Sorry for being such a clutz, for a tableview I could use id item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; and pull each item in the array [items] using the indexPath.row but how do I do it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `gridView's cellForRowAt` method you are using `same image link` for all `UIGridViewCell`.

`Get different link` from `feed` and depending on `rowIndex and column index` use `different image`

**EDIT** : For example i assume u have 4 images in row

```
 int column = 4;
 int row = totalImage / column;

 for(int i=1; i<=totalImage; i++)
 {
    for(int j=1; j<=row; j++)
    {
       for(int m=1; m<=column; m++)
       {
          // j and m 's image
       }
    }
 }
```